# XMLSerializiation stopping at declaration of Serializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

In my project I'm using a `List<Name>` for storing data.
Now I wanted to save the `List` via XMLSerialization:

```
                XmlSerializer listser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>)); //Stops here, jumps back to screen/GUI
                FileStream liststr = new FileStream(xmlSaveFile_Dialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                listser.Serialize(liststr, nameslist.list);
                liststr.Close();
```

Now the method simply stops at the `XmlSerializer` declaration.(There's no exception!)
I'm using exactly the same method before to serialize another object (`List<File>`).
This works without problems.

Now my code:
Name-Class:

```
    [Serializable()]
public class Name
{
    //[XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement("index")]
    public string index { get; set; }

    public Name(string name, string index)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Name-List:

```
 [XmlRoot("Units")]
class Namelist
{

    [XmlArray("Unitlist")]

    [XmlArrayItem("Unit", typeof(Name))]
    public List<Name> list;

    // Constructor
    public Namelist()
    {
        list = new List<Name>();
    }

    public void AddNameData(Name item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

In the main I declare this in the constructor:

```
nameslist = new NameList(); //this a global internal variable
```

Exactly the same way I did it with the `List<File>` object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` is not XML serializable in its present definition. The XML serializer cannot handle classes that lack a public parameterless ctor. So you should basically include the following ctor to `Name`:

```
public Name()
{
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KorrieSoab: Would you mind upvoting my answer, plus marking it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not having enough rep to upvote yet and I have to wait 5 more minutes to accept the answer, otherwise I would have done that already.